# Disjoint union of the same graph

Tags: graph-theory, notation, soft-question

In graph theory, the disjoint union of graphs $G_1,\dots,G_n$ is sometimes denoted by $G_1+\cdots+G_n$, or also by $\sum_{i=1}^nG_i$. In case $G_i=G$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$, is there another way to denote this disjoint union $\sum_{i=1}^nG$? Maybe $nG$?

I don't want to introduce a new notation in case there already exists one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $nG$ is certainly used for the disjoint union of $n$ copies of $G$. Here are some examples.

Definition 1.3.17 in West's *Introduction to Graph Theory*:

> The graph obtained by taking the union of graphs $G$ and $Η$ with disjoint vertex sets is the **disjoint union** or **sum**, written $G + H$. In general, $mG$ is the graph consisting of $m$ pairwise disjoint copies of $G$.

Diestel's *Graph Theory* generally writes out the disjoint union of copies of $G$ without notation, but does use the notation at one point in the middle of another definition:

> Let us call a graph $H$ *ubiquitous* with respect to a relation $\le$ between graphs (such as the subgraph relation $\subseteq $, or the minor relation $\preceq$) if $nH \le G$ for all $n \in N$ implies $\aleph_0 H \le G$, where $nH$ denotes the disjoint union of $n$ copies of $H$.

Also, one of my favorite papers in Ramsey theory, *Ramsey theory for multiple copies of graphs* by Burr, Erdős, and Spencer, uses the notation extensively because it's all about the Ramsey number $r(mG, nH)$. For example, it proves that $r(mK_3, nK_3) = 3m+2n$ when $m \ge n$ and $m\ge 2$.